# Is the following statement is True/false regarding a non-trivial homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following  statement True ?

> For every integer $n \geq 2$, there is a unique non-trivial homomorphism 
>   $\phi:S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$. where  $\mathbb{C}^*$,denotes  the multiplicative group of non-zero complex number.

My attempt  :  This   is  false,   because  this  only true  for   $n \le 4$ because cyclic  groups  map  to cyclic  group, as as  every finite   subgroup of $ \mathbb{C}^*$  is  cyclic

Is it  correct ?

Comment: Your argument does not really make sense to me. How does the image being cyclic rule out the existence of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ? $$g:\sigma \mapsto \begin{cases} 1&\text{if}\;\sigma \;\text{is even}\\-1 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

---

**Uniqueness :**

Suppose there is another non trivial homomorphism, say, $f$. Then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. But for $n \geq 5$, $A_n$ is the only proper normal subgroup of $S_n$. So $$\ker f\in\Big\{\{e\},A_n,S_n\Big\}$$

- $\ker f=S_n$ implies $f$ is trivial, which is not under consideration
- $\ker f=\{e\}$ implies $f(S_n)$ is a subgroup of order $6$ in $C^*$ and so cyclic, which is not true

Hence $\ker f=A_n$ and so $f=g$

Comment: im  not getting  can  u elaborate more ..

Comment: Are you preparing CSIR?

Comment: @Chinnaapparaj ya  im preparing  and what  about u ?

Comment: I see this question is in CSIR , that why I'm asking! & Yes to your second question. I already got lectureship, but this time, I try to got JRF!

Comment: @Chinnaapparj    can  u give  me some  tips  how  to qualify  csir  net ?  im  very  fear about  exam, ?  i

Comment: Are you going to write CSIR first time ?

Comment: see this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843703/book-recommendation-for-csir-ugc-net-exam/2843803#2843803) and my answer. I think it helps a little

Comment: no..this  is my second times,  last time  i didn't prepare  much

Comment: oksss let me see  and thanks u  so much

Comment: Don't worry and prepare well! first attempt part C and complete this section within 90 minutes and then move on to part B. Real Analysis, linear algebra and abstract algebra is ENOUGH to clear CSIR NET. All the best!

Comment: thanks  a lots once again and ur valuable  Guidance   i will try my best  effort @Chinnapparaj